# Prevent input margins from growing on zoom

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ruby

I have input fields which margins grow on zoom.

How can I stop this?

code:

css

```
input {
    background-color: white !important;
    border: 0.1vh solid black;
    width: 20%;
    height: 5vh;
    margin: 2.5vh;
    margin-left: 75%;
    padding-left: 2.5vh;
    font-size: 2vh;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Code is missing

Comment: @Laif and also `stop this` is missing

Comment: @Berto99 What are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this line:

```
margin-left: 75%;
```

Should be set to a viewport value. Something like:

```
margin-left: 10vw;
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2vendkh/8/) that might help things make more sense. Watch how the margins change (or don't) depending on your windows size and zoom level.

As you can see, pixel size doesn't change. The amount of pixels does! rem, em and px all define the margin by a set number of pixels. When less pixels are available (larger zoom) then the margin appears larger in relation to the content.

Percent bases the margin of the parent elements size. In the JSFiddles case, the preview window.

Last is viewport, or vh and vw. Theses are based as a percentage of the browsers width or height. If you browser is 1000px wide, then the margin: 10vw; is 10% of however wide the browser window is.

Answer (score 2):

Change your two `margin` styles to something related to `px` (pixels) or `rem`(line height) instead of `vh` (view height).

Comment: That males no sense - pixels get bigger on zoom - and also it didn't work